# Perl's \K in bash function

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

When I do

```
function replace { ( perl -i -slpe 's/^$string.*\K/$add/' -- -string="$1" -add="$2" $3 ) } 

replace 'passwd:' 'files dns' /tmp/1
```

I get

```
passwd:     filesfiles dns
group:      files
```

which should have been

```
passwd:     files dns
group:      files
```

The input files is

```
passwd:     files
group:      files
```

**Question**

Can anyone explain why it doesn't do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\K` and `.*` are in wrong place altogether, what you have done is with `^$string.*\K` is have matched the whole line(`.*` is greedy) before inserting the `\K` quantifier so that means the insertion happens after the whole line match. You should change it to be more effective as

```
perl -i -slpe 's/^$string\s+\K.*/$add/' -- -string="$1" -add="$2" "$3"
```

This way you take care of the proper spacing after the search string and add the replacement part after that. Also you don't need the `function` keyword in shell functions and also drop the `()` altogether and just do

```
replace () {
    perl -i -slpe 's/^$string\s+\K.*/$add/' -- -string="$1" -add="$2" "$3"
}
```